# polynomial function to recursive function?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

I am trying to create a sequence of polynomials,

$$s_n = \{x^0+x,\quad x^1+x,\quad x^2+x,\quad ...,\quad x^n+x\}$$

Using recursion.

That is, I want to "convert" $f(n) = x^n + x$ into a recursive function g(n). For example, I've found that
$$
\begin{aligned}
&f(n) = 2x^n + x = g(n,c), \quad n=c\\
&g(n,c) = x\cdot g(n-1,c) + \frac{1}{(c-1)x^{c-n-1}}\\
&g(0,c) = x+1,\quad g(1,c) = 2x\\
&n, c \quad\text{ (are natural numbers)}\\
&\text{e.g. } f(5) = g(5,5)
\end{aligned}
$$

But I don't know how to get a similar recursive function for $x^n+x$.

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. What is your definition of recursive function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $s_{n+1}= x(s_n-x)+x$?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks.

Comment: Note (for OP) that any time you have a sequence, whether its of numbers or functions or something else, and it's related to a different sequence that you understand better in an *invertible* way, then you can *conjugate* by the transformation that relates the two. In this case, the related sequence is $t_n = x^n$, which is clearly built by the recursive formula $t_{n+1} = x t_n$. The relationship is $s_n = t_n + x$, so $t_n = s_n - x$ and we recover the formula given in this answer:
$$
s_{n+1} = t_{n+1} + x = x t_n + x = x (s_n - x) + x.
$$

Comment: @SammyBlack - It's interesting, because my thinking was "that $x$ is sure complicating things. Let's set it to one side, and then I can put it back at the very end", which is exactly what you describe more formally.